# Properties of a macroscopic amount of virus

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

The mathematics YouTube channel *[Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile/videos)* just published a video entitled "[All the World's Coronavirus Fits in a Coke Can](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVgBjRFSMYs)" in which mathematician Kit Yates makes a [Fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) that all the SARS-CoV-2 coronavirus particles in the world would fit in a can of Coca-Cola (thereby missing the opportunity to make the pun that they would fit in a can of Corona beer).

What would the physical and chemical properties of such a macroscopic amount of coronavirus -- or even viruses in general other than coronavirus -- particles be? Would the mass as a whole seem solid or liquid-like? Would it be sticky? Would the viral particles attract or repel each other? What would it look like? Would it be transparent or opaque? What color, texture, smell, or other physical and chemical properties would it have?

Comment: It is a question rather to be answered by an article, or even a book, instead of a rather limited SE site answer. And the question is rather unfocud, forming a broad topic, that outstretches itself across many domains of science.
It would be look like something between a protein and nucleic acid.

Comment: It would depend on method of preparation.

Comment: Look for virus crystallisation.